# What is the easiest method to clean a bathroom floor that doesn't have a drain?

Tags: bathroom, cleaning

I recently moved to a new apartment and the bathroom does not have a floor drain. In my previous apartments, I used to pour/spray water on the bathroom floor while scrubbing with a brush and detergent, rinse it, then wait while the water drains off and dries. But I can't do that without a drain because the water puddles and seeps out under the door. Also, I am too lazy to use a mop and a bucket to clean the corners under the sink and behind the toilet.

Is there a fast and easy way to clean the bathroom without drowning the floor? Alternatively, is there a way to manage the water on the floor after cleaning the way I used to? Any suggestions for equipment/products that can be purchased online or at a convenient store that would make the process easier?

Comment: Unfortunately the only good answer I know is the one you claim to be too lazy for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no drain and you want to take the lazy way out, I'd suggest using a **steam mop** similar to the one pictured bellow. We picked up one of these a couple of weeks ago and are blown away by how well it cleans.

You just need to add water to the reservoir and then set the desired temperature, wait 30 seconds and you're set; barely any scrubbing required. Let the heat from the steam do the work.

As for water that you need to soak up after a bath or shower, a good old fashioned bath mat will do just fine.

[Google Images of a steam mop](https://www.google.ca/search?q=steam%20mop&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=QhXiU9L_HNevyAS_l4FI&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=670)

http://tsq.sewing.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/Bissell-Select-Steam-Mop-94E9T-Head-Height.jpg

Comment: The steam mop looks good, but a bit too big for a bathroom, would a [steam cleaner](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31YGXBJ358L.jpg) with a mop towel attachment work as well?

Comment: I could not view your attached image, and visiting the link directly returned a forbidden request

Comment: @Timmy re:size it's roughly the same size as a mop, just has something attached to it. I'm providing you this based on the fact **you said** you are too lazy to carry a bucket and cleaning supplies around. This is the ideal solution for you. The other nice thing about this is that it can be used in the rest of your apartment as well. Handles tiles, wood, vinyl any type of flooring.

Comment: @Timmy The steam cleaner *could* do the job, but, requires more work on your part. Steam mop is the way to go.